# Why did August 28th, 2019 Starhopper's test roll so much to the left?

Tags: spacex, attitude, spacex-starship

The last Starhopper [test flight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYb3bfA6_sQ) included a left roll of roughly 160°. It seems to have tried stopping the roll shortly after apogee using RCS thrusters, and once again shortly before touchdown.

What caused this seemingly unexpected roll?

Comment: I'd guess that if the roll had been intentional, RCS thrusters would have visibly initiated it before cancelling it out by firing in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Ingolifs unless it was "by-design" ;-)

Comment: @uhoh Well they *are* in Texas, and the building nearby *does* kinda look like a barn, so a [Texas sharpshooter fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter_fallacy) would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 possibilities:

1. SpaceX deliberately rolled it
2. It rolled naturally, and SpaceX did not expect / want this
3. It rolled naturally, and SpaceX did expect / want this.

Looking at the video, the roll seems to intensify without any use of the rcs thrusters, so it seems likely the roll occured naturally. In this case, the torque that induced the roll could either have come from the wind or from the engine. The wind would be pretty homogenous, so the engine is a far more likely source of torque. There may be some inherent swirl in the design of the injectors or it may simply be due minor variations within tolerances. Even if the swirl from the engine is theoretically zero, there will always in practice be a finite swirl and torque, and given the enormous thrust output this could easily be enough to cause the roll we saw.

It's also possible the engine is not mounted perfectly in the centre, so when it is gimballed to provide radial thrust in a direction perpendicular to the offset, it induces a torque.

As the engine's turbopumps have a vertical axis, they will also produce some inertial torque reaction whenever they change speed, but the engine was firing at a constant rate when the roll started, so I don't think that is relevant here.

The roll presumably must be removed before landing, so the RCS started to operate as the flight entered the descent phase. As the roll was not removed as soon as it started to occur, it seems likely SpaceX chose to allow the natural roll to develop. One important purpose of this flight will have been to test the guidance system of the prototype under powered flight. SpaceX probably thought that allowing the hopper to roll naturally for a while would give a better workout for guidance system controlling the engine gimbals, as well as more data on the natural tendency to roll.